# How do you automate GitHub pulls triggered by a webhook post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, automation, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using discord.js, and I've got them running from an offsite server so they can stay on 24/7.  As it stands right now, anytime I want to update them, I have to remote into the server, manually run a GitHub pull, and restart the bot.  I'm looking for a way to automate this.

I already have a Discord webhook set up to post anytime I run a push, but I'm hoping there's a way I can use that to trigger a pull on the server each time the webhook posts.  After a lot of google searches, it seems possible, but I'm not quite sure how to do it with my specific situation.  How can I automate GitHub pulls in this way?

Comment: You can use pm2 deploy process for this.
https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/easy-deploy-with-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

As @Narendra Kumawat mentioned in their comment, the PM2 Deploy feature is what I thought first. You can find the [docs here](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/easy-deploy-with-ssh/) to do this over SSH. I also found [this tutorial](https://dev.to/goodidea/setting-up-pm2-ci-deployments-with-github-actions-1494), featuring GitHub Actions (a very nice part of GitHub you should check out if you haven't yet)

Comment: Will I be able to do that entirely through code?  The goal is to first be able to make a bot command to trigger the pull, then I can easily use that to automate it based on the webhook post.